# Cross Updates between Models in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

when we speak about MVVM we speak about One Model that is used into the View Model to be displayed.
I have two Models that are dependent from each other. I can't write exactly the whole code because it is a professionnal project but here it is explicit enough

```
  public MyClass TestClass{

   //The constructor
   public TestClass(){
         _classB = new ClassB
         _classB.PropertyChanged += EventHandlerClassB
         _classA.PropertyChanged += EventHandlerClassA
    }

    private ClassB _classB;       

    public ClassB ClassB
    {
        get
        {
            return _classB;
        }
        set
        {
            _classB = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ClassB"));
            }


    }

    private ClassA _classA

    public ClassA classA
    {
        get
        {
            return _classA;
        }
        set
        {
            _classA = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ClassA"));
            }
        }
    }

    //the Event Handler
    private void EventHandlerClassB(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            UpdateA();
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e.PropertyName));
       }

    private void EventHandlerClassA (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            UpdateB();
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs    (e.PropertyName));
        }    

    }

}
```

Does Anybody have an Idea how to deal such Case? It creates an Infinity Loop.
In this case. Every properties from ClassA and From ClassB can Launch an Event with NotifyPropertyChangeEventHandler.

I am gooing into an infinit Loops.

Question Update:

After working on it I would like to be more spefic :
I have a PropertyGrid that Display two elements 
1) the whole ObservableCollection of Items where you add or remove elements

2) the second elements who is displayed is only an item of 
thatObservableCollection.

XAMl :

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="ModelA" AutoGenerateProperties="true" ShowSortOptions="True" SelectedObject="{Binding Path=ModelA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And ModelA contains :
    ObservableCollection WholeAlements;
    Items selectedItemA;

I can now select every Items from the ObservableCollection, but when modifying selectedItems it should affect the others too. Who to do it? Everything works fine with the ObservableCollection but not with the selectedItemA

Answer (score 0):

Don't fire the PropertyChanged event unless the property has actually changed.

```
private ClassA _classA;
public ClassA classA
{
    get
    {
        return _classA;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_classA != value)
        {
            _classA = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ClassA"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your update methods actually return a different value every time, then you will need to either break the interdependency, or partition A and B such that they don't trigger each other's updates automatically (example: remove the event handlers and force a user to click a button to trigger simultaneous updates).

Answer (score 0):

VMs should be independent. If you need to communicate between VMs, you can use the messenger pattern to send messages back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You update some property in class A and that triggers an update in class B and that (again) triggers an update in class A and so on? If that's the case, something's wrong with your model, and you're not going to solve it by whatever communication you implement between your view models, because your model is never in a stable state but oscillating as the updates happen. Either A or B is always outdated.

If you can remove the oscillation and unify classes A and B into a model that has a stable state, then let view models A and B visualize that state, and update the visualization when the state changes in the model. The view models should update the model and the model should notify all interested view model (perhaps through `INotifyPropertyChanged`) when its state changes so they can updated themselves.

EDIT: If the user edits the currently selected item, and then modifies the collection by adding or removing other items, just commit the edits to the selected item. If he edits the selected item and then deletes *that* from the collection, discard the changes... Nevertheless, you have to find a model where changes to one item cannot influence the collection and then have an effect back on the original item.

Comment: To be more specific :  It is exactly the Idea I had. If ClassA is a Kind of observableCollection and it can be modified. And at the same time we let the User the Option to work only on a current selected item of that Kind Of Observablecollection what Kind of possibilities do I have? In fact in A propertyGrid the User can Display all the elements available into the Collection then Add, remove, or Rework elements. The other Option he have is to modifiy only the current selected item, these modifications of the current Item influence the Whole elements in the Collection.